# android physics engine

Tags: android, physics-engine

After looking into 3D game programming, it quickly became evident why a physics engine could be extremely useful.
What physics engines are supported by and viable on Android?
Any other advice regarding them would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034253/are-there-any-decent-physics-engines-for-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not 3D, but [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) could at least provide you some useful information to start with. It is a very promising and free Open Source 2D OpenGL Game Engine for the Android platform.

Have a look at their [example application](http://www.appbrain.com/app/andengine-examples/org.anddev.andengine.examples) to see what it can do :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a 2D JavaScript engine that looks interesting: [Box2D](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The latest Matali Physics Pro supports Android OS through the Mono for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Or you use http://jmonkeyengine.org/ which is in my optinion one of the most advanced game/graphics/3d physics engines available for Android and in comparison to Unity3d its open source and can be embedded in existing Android apps ;)

Answer (score 0):

For 3D a good option is Unity3d which supports Android (and iOS) game development and is a complete solution used by many big players. It also supports 2D. There is a free version, but pro is not free though., it's pretty expensive ($400 - $1.500.

http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/mobile

For 2D, Box2d has an Android port: https://code.google.com/p/androidbox2d/